# Why was my answered question about self help from experienced users deleted?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, deleted-questions

A few seconds ago [my question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/174980/im-not-very-serious) (>10k) was deleted. So I need an explanation. And avoid myself of further explaining this!

Comment: Do you have a link to your deleted question? That would help.

Comment: Got a link to it?

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/174980/im-not-very-serious (you need 10K on MSO to see it, but the url slug is pretty accurate)

Comment: @Yannis, oh, that one? I'm not sure what can be done, then.

Comment: Well, to be honest, it was not much of a question. Either you need to clarify what it is you're asking. Or if Yannis' answer perfectly answered your question, it's off-topic.

Comment: I honestly did not even understand your deleted question.

Answer (score 12):

I deleted it.  While I'm not unsympathetic to what you might be experiencing with your interactions on Stack Exchange, you've indicated that it's a purely personal problem.

This is something that is off topic for Meta Stack Exchange.  Since there's very little chance that can be turned into something constructive or of use to Meta, I deleted it.

Again, while not unsympathetic, this is not the place to ask such questions if you know there are issues you have to address with yourself.

Meta is for addressing issues with the site, not how the site affects you.

Comment: Feature request: per-user meta sites.

Comment: @BoltClock'saUnicorn Each with a moderator team of their own.

Comment: "I deleted it." Hey! My delete vote is there as well ;P

Comment: @BoltClock'saUnicorn I think I'm submitting an Area51 proposal for an "Andrew Barber" Q/A site!

Comment: @AndrewBarber I would support your proposal.

Comment: I've got it, Casper-Janis conjecture. +My appeal to doctors of my answer of my topic (in reply to comments+accepted answer): I think most of professional Ukrainian physicians are having some troubles with professional English forums. +Pekka, you could make head nor tail of it..